# creating a flask form which uses data from another table as input

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am just beginning with python and flask and am looking to create an app.  The app allows users to enter their favourite artists in one page.  In the next page then allows the user to enter favourite tracks using SelectField where the artist names are given as the options.

I have the following

models:

```
    from application import db
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, BooleanField, IntegerField, SelectField

class Artist(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    artist_name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    music_artist = db.relationship('Music', backref='musicbr') 

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Choose {}'.format(self.artist_name)

class Music(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    track_name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'), nullable=False)
    
class AddArtistForm(FlaskForm):
    artist_name = StringField('Artist Name')
    submit = SubmitField('Add Artist!')

class AddMusicForm(FlaskForm):
    track_name = StringField('Track Name')
    artist_name = SelectField('Artist Name', coerce=int)
    submit = SubmitField('Add Track!')enter code here
```

and the following routes

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add_artist', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def add_artist():
    form = AddArtistForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_artist = Artist(artist_name =form.artist_name.data)
        db.session.add(new_artist)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('index.html', message="Artist Added!")
    else:
        return render_template('add_artist.html', form=form)



   @app.route('/add_music', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def add_music():
    form = AddMusicForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_track = Music(track_name =form.track_name.data)
        artist_choice = Artist.query.all(artist_name=form.artist_name.data)
        db.session.add(new_track)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('index.html', message="Track Added!")
    else:
        return render_template('add_music.html', form=form)
```

Is someone able to help me to understand what code I need to implement here?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  In the end I used the following solution:    
artist_name = SelectField(u'Artist Name', choices = []) in the form. which generated the choices dropdown.  The choices was then populated within the routing function using an iterating query :                                                            form.artist_name.choices = [(artist.id, artist.artist_name) for artist in Artist.query.order_by(Artist.artist_name).all()]